# Вывести вычисляемые значения из массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть рабочий код который прибавляет количество дней к дате

```
<p>Колиество дней: <input v-model="message">«{{ message }}»</p>
<p>Дата: <input v-model="messdate">«{{ messdate }}»</p>
<p>Итоговая дата: «{{ reversedMessage }}»</p>
```

```
data: {
    message: 1,
        messdate: '2020,05,07',
        resultMessage: ''
},
computed: {
    reversedMessage() {
        var D = new Date(this.messdate);
        D.setDate(D.getDate() + this.message);
        return this.resultMessage = ('0' + D.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('0' + (D.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + D.getFullYear();
    }
},
```

Как убрать поле ввода количество дней и вывести из массива типа такого вида? Код ругается с ошибкой

```
days:[
    {day:'10'},
    {day:'20'},
    {day:'30'},
],
```

```
<p v-for="item in days">{{ reversedMessage(item.day) }}</p>
```

Comment: Что за ошибка? Что в целом вы хотите сделать? Плюс `reversedMessage` это вычисляемое свойство, а вы его как `method` вызываете. Перенесите его из `computed` в `methods`

Comment: я хочу чтоб при каждой итерации массива вызывало функцию с вычислением даты + количество дней в каждом элементе, то есть 2020,05,07 + 10 дней ,2020,05,07 + 20 дней ,2020,05,07 + 30 дней

Answer (score 1):

`reversedMessage` - это вычисляемое свойство, а не функция, поэтому и ошибка. Перенесите его в `methods` из `computed`